# How to download a WebJob executable/script from AppService

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

We've taken over an Azure environment for a client from a previous vendor. The previous vendor has installed a few WebJobs on the AppService but hasnt committed the code to git. Since relations with previous vendor ended badly, there is no way to retrieve the source code. I've been trying to find the executable in App Service but they aren't there under D:\home\data\jobs\triggered<JobName> all I find here are logs. Where are the executables/scripts for WebJobs saved?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Comment: @StanleyGong I couldnt find the executable or script files where you've shown then in your answer. I found them inside the temp folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your Webjobs executables binary file or Script file, you can find them under the folder :

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Triggered
```

[image]